# Get URL Referer [BotFramework-WebChat]

Tags: botframework, direct-line-botframework

I'm using a directline inside my website and I was wondering if there is anyway to get the URL of the website inside my bot code. Previously, in v3, I was initializing the chat with:

```
 BotChat.App({
        directLine: { secret: "{directline_secret}" },
        user: { id: 'You', referrer: window.location.href},
        bot: { id: '{bot_id}' },
        resize: 'detect'
    }, document.getElementById("bot"));
```

and I was able to get the referrer with this line of code `activity.From.Properties["referrer"].ToString()`, but in v4 I can't find a way to get the referrer inside the bot.

Can someone help me?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: To be clear, you are trying to get the URL of the user, correct?

Comment: Yes I am. You are correct.

Answer (score 0):

In v4 the value is part of the turnContext.activity (in Node) or turnContext.Activity (in C#) object. Passing the url value as you have done in your question (i.e., as part of the user object) you would access it like so (Node example):

```
async onTurn(turnContext) {

    if (
        turnContext.activity.type === "event" && turnContext.activity.name === "eventName"
    ) {
        this.userProfile.location = turnContext.activity.from.referrer;
        await console.log(this.userProfile.location);
    }
```

I included a name as well as specified a type in my BotChat.App post to match *this* event to in the turnContext.activity:

```
function testMethod(someValue) {
  botConnection
    .postActivity({
      from: { id: 'me', referrer: window.location.href },
      name: 'eventName',
      type: 'event',
      value: someValue
    })
    .subscribe(function (id) {
      console.log('"eventName" sent');
    });
};
```

In this example, the method is tied to a button being pressed on the page.

Hope of help!